# foreach loop using $_POST data and creating email notification

Tags: php

I am attempting to update a db table based on changes made in a tablesorter table.  I am sending the information through JS and each item is posted to the php page that will handle the update.  This works fine.  I now need to have it send an email that shows the buyer name, and the new date processed so that we can calculate commissions from it.  When I added my foreach loop, I get 45 separate emails, not just one.
Do I need to add another foreach loop or is there something else that I need to do?
Here is the code for the php page:

```
    <?php
require_once ('../db.php');
$conn = db_connect();
session_start();


$buyer = $_POST['buyer'];
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
$sku = $_POST['sku'];
$cost = $_POST['cost'];
$csmt = $_POST['csmt'];
$hold = $_POST['hold'];
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$n=1;

foreach($sku as $value){ 
// update inventory table
$conn->query("update inventory set cost = $cost, csmt = $csmt, hold = $hold, date_process = $today where sku = $sku");


$holdList[$n] = array('buyer' => $buyer,
            'process date' => $today,
                );
$n++;
}
//loop trough hold list and store in csv format
$csvLists = to_csv($holdList);


function to_csv( $array ) {
 $csv = "";

 if (count($array) == 0) return "No Information found";

 ## Grab the first element to build the header
 $arr = array_pop( $array );
 $temp = array();
 foreach( $arr as $key => $data ) {
   $temp[] = $key;
 }
 $csv = implode( ',', $temp ) . "\r\n";

 ## Add the data from the first element
 $csv .= to_csv_line( $arr );

 ## Add the data for the rest
 foreach( $array as $arr ) {
   $csv .= to_csv_line( $arr );
 }

 return $csv;
}

function to_csv_line( $array ) {
 $temp = array();
 foreach( $array as $elt ) {
   $temp[] = '"' . addslashes( $elt ) . '"';
 }

 $string = implode( ',', $temp ) . "\r\n";

 return $string;
}

$conn->close();

$pricingReport = "The Latest Hold List has been completed. \n";
$pricingReport .= $csvLists;

//send email when pricing specs are done
$to = "jimd@bookcellaronline.com";

$subject = "Hold List";
$body = $pricingReport;
mail($to, $subject, $body);

?>
```

UPDATE:  Here is the JS:

```
    // to save the changes to the hold table
$("#holdSave").live('click', function() {
$('#holdTable tbody tr').each(function()
        {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "holdSave.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: ({buyer: $(this).find('#tableBuyer').html(), sku: $(this).find('#tableSku').html(), isbn: $(this).find('#tableISBN').html(),
           cost: $(this).find('#tableCost').val(), csmt: $(this).find('#tableConsignment').val(),
           hold: $(this).find('#tableHold').val()}),
    success: function(data) {

        } // end of success function

}); // end of ajax call
                    }); // end of holdtable tbody function
}); // end of holdSave event
```

Comment: What is in the 45 mails you receive? Your call to `mail()` is not inside a loop so unless you are calling this script 45 times I don't see what's causing that.

Comment: Note, this script is vulnerable to SQL injection. Assuming this is MySQLi, be sure to call `$whatever = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['whatever']);` on your form inputs

Comment: I think the problem might be your Javascript calling the page 45 times. Can you show your script?

Comment: @Michael - I get one email for each record in the table.  I am trying to get one email that lists all 45 buyers and date processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax function is being called individually for each record due to which you are getting a mail for each record.

What you can do is make an JSON object with the entire dataset and then invoke the ajax call:

```
var arr={};
var cnt=0;
$('#holdTable tbody tr').each(function()
{
    arr[cnt]={buyer: $(this).find('#tableBuyer').html(), sku: $(this).find('#tableSku').html(), isbn: $(this).find('#tableISBN').html(),
       cost: $(this).find('#tableCost').val(), csmt: $(this).find('#tableConsignment').val(),
       hold: $(this).find('#tableHold').val()};
    cnt++;
}
```

Then, pass this object in the ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "holdSave.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {data:arr},
    success: function(data) {

    } // end of success function
    });
```

On php side, you can parse the $_POST['data'] for each record.

```
$data=$_POST['data'];
```

The individual elements of `$data` are the records you have to insert.
They can be parsed in a simple for loop as `$data[$i]['buyer']`,`$data[$i]['sku']` ...

Comment: I am a little confused, I have never had to process an object from json into an array in php.  Could you please explain a little so I can learn this?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I have been trying what you suggested and I am not getting any information returned when I do print_r($data[0]['sku']); die; from my php side.  I know the data is going into the json ok though.  Any ideas??

Comment: Can you check if `var_dump($_POST['data'])` returns anything? If so, then you would understand from the output what the data is being passed like.

Comment: I was able to get this working last night.  Thanks for all the help.